# Duplicate rows are not getting deleted?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Deleting duplicate rows in sqlite or in sqlite using python ! is not working.

Here is the code which I had written:

```
cur.execute('select name1, min(rowid) from company group by name1')
```

This is the file:

```
#rowid | name1  
1      | Havoc  
2      | Google  
3      | Google  
4      | Havoc
```

I want to get it as below in another column:

```
#name2  
Havoc  
Google
```

I'm getting some unsorted output.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT name1 from company')
```